Binary File Read with Large Data Set in C++ Throws std::bad_alloc
title:
Binary File Read with Large Data Set in C++ Throws std::bad_alloc
Body:
I'm working on a C++ project where I need to read approximately 2 million Player objects from a binary file and store them in a container. However, my attempt to load these objects results in a std::bad_alloc exception. I suspect the issue might be related to memory allocation for the std::vector or the way I handle binary file I/O. Here's a simplified version of my Player class and the main function that attempts to read the file
 class Player {
    public:
        std::string name;  // Length [3, 15]
        int score;
        size_t id;
        size_t num;
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> p;  // Memory allocated on the heap

    bool read(std::istream& is) {
        // Read fixed-size part of Player object
        if (!is.read((char*)this, sizeof(Player) - sizeof(std::unique_ptr<char[]>))) {
            return false;
        }

        // Allocate memory for the dynamic part
        p = std::make_unique<char[]>(num);
        if (!is.read(p.get(), num)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    int main() {
        std::string filename = "file";
        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
        if (!file) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    
        std::vector<Player> players;
        players.reserve(2000000);  // Pre-allocate memory for 2 million players

        while (true) {
            Player player;
            if (!player.read(file)) break;
            players.push_back(std::move(player));
        }

        std::cout << "Loaded " << players.size() << " players." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }


Data is no longer added and deleted, only sorted and navigated I can use other containers
The file was opened as a binary (ios::binary) and the
and uses the write member function to write two million Player objects.
void Player::write( ostream& os ) {
os.write((char*)this, sizeof(Player));
os.write((char*)p.get(), num);
}



Is players.reserve(2000000); what throws the exception?

read((char*)this,... looks like a bad idea. You can't read into a std::string like that. You'd better serialize it properly instead.

You are doing a binary read into a std::string object. That does not work. Effectively you are reading the pointers that the string object contains directly from the file.

If your name is always with a length of 3 to 15 (which is what the comments suggest) then the simplest thing would be char name[16];. Then your binary read should work.

// Read fixed-size part of Player object -- There is no way this is going to work.  Others have explained it, but here is another simple explanation -- look at the parameter in the read and write functions that denote the number of bytes to read/write.  It uses sizeof(Player).  Assume that the std::string member contained 1000 characters -- since sizeof is a compile-time value, it has no idea there are actually 1000 characters that need to be read and written.  So right there, you see the read and write could never work properly.

See this.  You see that sizeof remains 64, even if you placed 1000 characters into std::string name.

You are writing a different amount of data to what you are reading.
void Player::write( ostream& os ) {
  os.write((char*)this, sizeof(Player)); 
  os.write((char*)p.get(), num);
}

This totals sizeof(Player) + num bytes.
bool read(std::istream& is) {
    // Read fixed-size part of Player object
    if (!is.read((char*)this, sizeof(Player) - sizeof(std::unique_ptr<char[]>))) {
        return false;
    }

    // Allocate memory for the dynamic part
    p = std::make_unique<char[]>(num);
    if (!is.read(p.get(), num)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

This totals sizeof(Player) - sizeof(std::unique_ptr<char[]>) + num bytes.
The discrepancy means that for the second Player that you read in, you are initialising num from the initial data of *p. Quite plausibly this is a value way above the available space on your system, so std::make_unique<char[]>(num) fails, throwing std::bad_alloc.
It is also not portable, and in general not safe, to write the object representation of a std::string. If, as the comments suggest, you have a nul terminated string of at most 15 characters, the type you want for name is char[16]. You could add a member function returning a std::string_view for some use cases.
class Player {
    public:
    char name[16];
    int score;
    size_t id;
    size_t num;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> p;  // Memory allocated on the heap

    bool read(std::istream& is) {
        // Read fixed-size part of Player object
        if (!is.read((char*)this, sizeof(Player) - sizeof(std::unique_ptr<char[]>))) {
            return false;
        }

        // Allocate memory for the dynamic part
        p = std::make_unique<char[]>(num);
        if (!is.read(p.get(), num)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void write(std::ostream& os) {
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(Player) - sizeof(std::unique_ptr<char[]>));
        os.write(p.get(), num);
    }

    std::string_view name_str() { return { name }; }
};

